# Pandas convert series of one to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a data frame with a lot of columns and rows, the index column contains datetime objects.

```
date_time            column1  column2
10-10-2010 00:00:00  1        10
10-10-2010 00:00:03  1        10
10-10-2010 00:00:06  1        10
```

Now I want to calculate the difference in time between the first and last datetime object. Therefore:

```
start = df["date_time"].head(1)
stop = df["date_time"].tail(1)
```

However I now want to extract this datetime value so that I can use the .total_seconds() seconds to calculate the number of seconds difference between the two datetime objects, something like:

```
delta_t_seconds = (start - stop).total_seconds()
```

This however doesn't give the desired result, since start and stop are still series with only one member.

please help

Comment: Try to use `.values[0]`, as such: `(start.values[0] - stop.values[0]).total_seconds()`

Comment: Instead of `head(0)` and `last(0)` use [`Series.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html#pandas-series-iat) i.e `iat[0]`, `iat[-1]`